# Algebraically showing 2 quaternions compose a new rotation

Tags: rotations, quaternions

I am trying to **algebraically**  prove that multiplying 2 quaternion rotations produces a new quaterion rotation. This is what I have so far:

[image]
[image]
[image]

After lots of simplifying, I get here:
[image]

I see the first term has the cosine part of the combined quaternion. I almost have the second term of rodrigues rotation formula in the second term. I am having a hard time figuring out how I can simplify down to the the rest of the rodrigues rotation formula to show that applying 2 quaternions is equivalent to applying the composed quaternion.

Comment: Why do you do it the hard way? We know that every quaternion with length one represents a rotation. So all we have to show is that the product of two unit quaternions is a unit quaternion. The easiest way to do this is to represent quaternions as complex $2\times 2$-matrices and use the fact that the squared length of the quaternion is the determinant. Then use what you know about the determinant of the product of two matrices.

Comment: In the same way as @Kurt G. : The rotation associated with $q_1$ is $R_{1}(v) = q_1^{-1}vq_1$ where $q_1$ is a *purely vectorial* quaternion ; same thing for $q_2$, then composing them amounts to do :  $R_2 \circ R_{1}(v) = q_2^{-1}q_1^{-1}vq_1q_2$

Comment: Define $\phi_n := 2\theta_n$ where $n=1$ or $n=2$ to make things much simpler.